# UI automation of mouse click at logon screen in windows 8.1

Tags: user-interface, ui-automation, mouseclick-event, winlogon, startupscript

For UI automation testing purposes, I need to click a button on the windows 8.1 logon screen where it prompts to select a user account. And no, I do not need to select a user account. Its a button in particular. I am not quite sure how to do it. I tried to include my script as a Group Policy (gpedit.msc) startup script but its not working. But the same works when I include it as a Group Policy logon script.

I tried to directly include it in the registry as well under Group Policy startup scripts but it didn't work. Adding the script in the registry to be executed at logon works. My script is in Python.

Has anyone done anything like this by adding their script through gpedit.msc? (I might be doing something wrong at this step in that case). Other methods and ideas are good too. Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "work" when you run script as logon script. Does it click to the button on logon screen somehow? Logon screen is shown on "protected" desktop and thus cannot be accessed easily. I suspect your script should switch to this desktop to make automation